# How do I get a Watermark image on the Report in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I need a Watermark Image in every page on the Report which I have built on Acumatica Report Designer. Is there a way to do it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a watermark by setting the Style->BackImage property of the report or a particular section of the report. The image can be embedded in the report. To set an embedded image, look for the EmbeddedImages property in the Data section of the report.

Comment: Awesome ! Works !